# How $A$ can be divided to $n+1$ sets $a = \cup_{i=0}^n A_i$ such that $diam(A_i) \lt 1$ for $i=0,...,n.$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, convex-analysis

**Given:** Let $ A \subset \mathbb R^n$ be a closed convex set with smooth boundary and diameter $diam(A) = 1$.

**Question:** How $A$ can be divided to $n+1$ sets $a = \cup_{i=0}^n A_i$ such that $diam(A_i) \lt 1$ for $i=0,...,n.$

I'm still not sure how to approach this, any hints/approaches wouch be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do the sets $A_i$ need to be convex? How would you do it in $\mathbb{R}^2$ if $A = \{x : \|x\| \leq 1\}$?

Comment: Are the sets connected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible for $n$ large enough: [Borsuk's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borsuk%27s_conjecture)

Comment: It is an interesting article +1

Answer (score 1):

For n = 2, let p, the geometric center of A, be placed at (0,0).
A is a subset of a closed disk D with radius 1/2 centered at p.

Draw a line u from p at a 45 degree angle from the x-axis.
Draw a line v from p at a -45 degree angle from the x-axis.

The wedge between u and v is one part.
For the other two parts divided the disk without the wedge by the x-axis.

Use the conditions on A to prove this construction divides A into three not empty convex subsets.